# Custom page variable in OctoberCMS

Tags: php, octobercms

Is it possible to use custom page variable in Configuration section in OctoberCMS?
When I do this:

```
url = "/blog"
layout = "default"

custom_var = "value"
==
{{ custom_var }}
```

my **custom_var** is deleting when edit page from admin panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this was the `old` way of defining all stuff in single view (visual representation)

now its divided in 3 portion

**1st** `name and url(slug)` then **2nd** `markup(html) section`

[image]

**3rd** `code section`

[image]

so you can follow `new way` of `declaring` things and it should work

use `code section` add this

```
public function onStart() {
    $this['custom_var'] = 'some value';
}
```

use `markup` section and add this

```
<h1>{{ custom_var }}</h1>
```

it will work, still any issue please comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to use this variable in my layout like this `{{ this.page.custom_var }}` and not in html-section of this page. Is it possible?

Comment: you can use this in layout as well `{{ custom_var }}` this will work also

Comment: even in layout you could use same thing as its also divided in markup and section. (can you share more details how you need to use this and where in question section)

Comment: I need to add some different meta-properties into <head> tag in layout depending on the page. I wanted to add some variable, set different values on different pages and check it's value in layout. But I've decided to use `this.page.baseFileName` - it is also unique. Thank for your help!

Comment: ok, cool that will also work, but be `careful` during changing `name of file` as its `baseFilename` so, other wise it will work `perfectly`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, its possible to set custom variable into page. you can try the following code into the php section

```
function onEnd() {
    $this->page->custom_var = 'some data';
}
```

And then you can use this custom_var into your layout file like

```
{{ this.page.custom_var }}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define new variables inside markup you can use following syntax:

```
{% set custom_var = 'some data' %}
```